# beaglebone a6 setting cross compile - cannot execute binary. Wrong abi version?

Tags: eclipse, cross-compiling

I am trying to setup Eclipse to build binaries for beaglebone a6. On bb I have Debian stable wheezy and on my PC I have Arch installed. Using gcc linaro 4.9 but it won't work:

```
gdbserver :2345 /home/dragonn/bbcpp;exit
dragonn@debian:~$ echo $PWD'>'
/home/dragonn>
dragonn@debian:~$ gdbserver :2345 /home/dragonn/bbcpp;exit
Process /home/dragonn/bbcpp created; pid = 2158
Cannot exec /home/dragonn/bbcpp: No such file or directory.

Child exited with status 127
No program to debug.  GDBserver exiting.
logout
```

file command shows this:

```
root@debian:/home/dragonn# file bbcpp
bbcpp: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.4.104, BuildID[sha1]=0xb9518d4e4550dfa8ac66db0625ed514460bc70d7, not stripped
root@debian:/home/dragonn# file a.out 
a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0x2dc9c698a5186e4ca4ca78c9d698ff92ecabc377, not stripped
```

bbcpp is complied via Eclipse and a.out directly on bb. I think the ABI version of my binary is to high? I am right? How can I change that?

Comment: You really need the same toolchain as you have on BB: gcc-4.7-armeabihf. If you want to avoid such problems from the very beginning try other distribution like [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) or [Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/).

Comment: Thanks. I will give a try next days. An other workaround is using static flag when compiling but this isn't the best solution.